# NativeModules is null for android native module [react-native]

Tags: android, react-native, background-task, native-module

I'm trying to create a native android module to create background tasks.
I try to follow this tutorial : https://blog.logrocket.com/run-react-native-background-tasks-headless-js/

But when I try to call my module like this :

```
NativeModules.BackgroundWorkManager.startBackgroundWork();
```

I get "Cannot read property 'startBackgroundWork' of null".
so why my import NativeModules is null ? :

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
```

My js file :

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, ImageBackground, StyleSheet, FlatList, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import GeolocationSvc from '../Services/GeolocationSvc';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
import {AppContext} from '../Providers/AppProvider';
import {calculateDistance} from '../Utiles';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';

const PlaceItem = ({data}) =>{
    const [state, dispatch] = useContext(AppContext);
    const [distance, setDistance] = useState(null);
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const onPress = (id) => {
        NativeModules.BackgroundWorkManager.startBackgroundWork();
        navigation.navigate('SinglePlaceScreen', {placeId: id});
    }
    
    ...

    return (
        ...
    )
    }
    ...
```

I declared this in my MainApplication.java

```
 @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          
          packages.add(new BackgroundPackage());
  
        
          return packages;
        }
```

BackgroundPackage.java

```
package com.mystere;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class BackgroundPackage implements ReactPackage {
    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(@Nonnull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        modules.add(new BackgroundModule(reactContext));
        return modules;
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(@Nonnull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    
}
```

My BackgroundModules.java :

```
package com.mystere;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class BackgroundModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    private static final String MODULE_NAME = "BackgroundWorkManager";

    private Context mContext;
    private PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest;

    BackgroundModule(@Nonnull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        mContext = reactContext;
        workRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(BackgroundWorker.class, 20, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void startBackgroundWork() {
        WorkManager.getInstance(mContext).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("testWork", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,workRequest);
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void stopBackgroundWork() {
        WorkManager.getInstance(mContext).cancelUniqueWork("testWork");
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return MODULE_NAME;
    }
}
```

My MainApplication.java

```
package com.mystere;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage;
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage;
import com.mystere.BackgroundPackage;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          packages.add(new BackgroundPackage());
  
        
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
        @Override 
        protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() { 
          return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage(); 
          }


      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
    
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.mystere.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: There's an open issue about this on React Native's GitHub - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26813 - lots of things to try there, no clear answer unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have on your BackgroundModule.java:

```
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "BackgroundWorkManager";
  }
```

Comment: I have added but it's still null :/

Comment: Could you update your question with the content of BackgroundPackage.java?

Comment: I updated my answer, you need to add getName to your BackgroundModule not BackgroundPackage

Comment: @AureoBack  I updated my post with BackgroundModule file how already had getName() function. Maybe something else in this file ?  Thanks

Comment: It seems correct, could you share your full MainApplication.java as well?

Comment: update is done :)

Comment: I can't see any problems there, maybe try to rebuild your application, be sure to rebuild using:

`npx react-native run-android`

And restart bundle with:

`npm start -- --reset-cache`